# How to retrieve data from URL path with React?

Tags: reactjs, express

On my server side I'am doing this with express :

```
app.get('/rooms/:id', function(req, res) {

      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/index.html'));
  });
```

This sends an index.html file containing a React component. How can I retrieve the ":id" in the URLfrom within the React component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer :

assuming you avoid all other libraries and frameworks, you can simply use the location global variable, you will however need to destruct the query params and map them to your argument (usually located inside location.search).

The complex answer:

Most routing libraries(including React Router) will expose an interface to both describe and map GET variables to named variables.

Comment: I tried using the location global variable but when I do console.log(window.location), it throws: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: Are you using client side React or Server side?

Comment: Gosh...I think I need some rest

Comment: You're more than likely using clientSide React, however it could also be your build tool that's hiding window, will be hard to say without seeing index.html itself

Answer (score 0):

The url params are located inside the `req.params` object.

```js
app.get('/rooms/:id', function(req, res) {

  let roomId = req.params.id;
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/src/index.html'));
  });
```

Comment: But how can I retrieve the roomId from the other side ?